# How to disable not selected array and enable selected array?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Can someone help me how to disable not selected array and enable selected array?
I am having problem on how to do it.. I am new to unity and i am really having a problem learning on it. I have search in other platform but failed to get the answer. So please don't bash me for something i don't know yet :(

anyway thank you for answering...

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ArrayObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public GameObject[] CustomPanel;
    private int counter = 0;
    public GameObject nextBtn;
    public GameObject prevBtn;
    void Start()
    {

    }
    private void checkBtns()
    {
        if (counter < 1)
        {
            prevBtn.SetActive(false);
        }
        else
        {
            prevBtn.SetActive(true);
        }
        if (counter > CustomPanel.Length - 2)
        {
            nextBtn.SetActive(false);
        }
        else
        {
            nextBtn.SetActive(true);
        }
    }

    public void next()
    {
        counter++;
        checkBtns();
        CustomPanel[counter].SetActive(true);
    }
    public void prev()
    {
        counter--;
        checkBtns();
        CustomPanel[counter].SetActive(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you clairfy what you're asking? You only have one array declared here.

Comment: for example i have 5 array stored and I want to show the 3 then 1,2,4,5 must be disabled for you see its a gameobject.

Comment: An array is a fixed-size collection of items. When you say "array", do you actually mean "array item"? Are you just talking about the `CustomPanel` array, rather than 5 arrays?

Comment: Custompanel array I'm really sorry to confuse you. i am having problem in my English sorry.

Comment: I'm still not 100% clear on what you're trying to do, but it's a little clearer now. I think you will need to use a [`for` loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for) to go through the items in the array, enabling and disabling them according to your requirements.

Comment: i found another way to do it. thank you for your sharing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void next()
{
    counter++;
    checkBtns();
    for (int i = 0; i < CustomPanel.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i == counter)
            CustomPanel[i].SetActive(true);
        else
            CustomPanel[i].SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

or

```
public void next()
{
    counter++;
    checkBtns();
    for (int i = 0; i < CustomPanel.Length; i++)
    {
        CustomPanel[i].SetActive(i == counter);
    }
}
```

Another option: to not iterate through all the objects in the array:

```
public void next()
{
    // Disable the button that has been selected
    // before the click.
    // The counter is currently = that button index.
    CustomPanel[counter].SetActive(false);
    counter++;
    checkBtns();
    // Now the counter = the new button index,
    // enable the newly selected button:
    CustomPanel[counter].SetActive(true);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I get the answer by using foreach.